# reverse ssh tunnel listens on wrong interface

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I'm working with a server that is behind a firewall. I have established an ssh tunnel to an intermediate server in the internet like this:

```
remoteuser@behind_fw$ ssh -N -f -R 10002:localhost:22 middleuser@middle
```

But I can't connect directly throgh this server, this doesn't work:

```
user@local$ ssh remoteuser@middle -p 10002
```

I have to connect in two steps:

```
user@local$ ssh middleuser@middle
middleuser@middle$ ssh remoteuser@localhost -p 10002
```

Output of `netstat -l` on middle:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:10002         *:*                     LISTEN
```

but it should be something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 *:10002                 *:*                     LISTEN
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This being a tunnel opened at a remote server, that server needs to have **GatewayPorts** set to **yes** in its /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Depending on what kind of users that server have you might want to use the **Match** option to limit that capability to your user.

```
Match User middleuser
  GatewayPorts yes
```

Do note that you probably want to add this Match block in the end of your sshd_config, since a Match block goes on until another one begins, or the file ends.

That being said, how about instead trying what I'd consider a slightly cleaner solution?

```
user@local$ ssh -N -f -L 10002:behind_fw:22 middleuser@middle
user@local$ ssh remoteuser@localhost -p 10002
```

Comment: Also try `GatewayPorts clientspecified` to make ssh obey your orders.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/379344/selecting-interface-for-ssh-port-forwarding/379347#379347

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using OpenSSH you need to specify the bind address. Try something like:

```
ssh -N -f -R *:10002:localhost:22 middleuser@middle
```

or

```
ssh -N -f -R :10002:localhost:22 middleuser@middle
```

The signature for -R is:

```
-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

on OpenSSH. For security reasons it defaults to localhost if you don't specify it. You might have to change GatewayPorts to get it to work depending on your config. See [SSH(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1) for more info.