# Selecting Interface for SSH Port Forwarding

Tags: ssh, port, forwarding

I have a server that we'll call hub-server.tld with three IP addresses 100.200.130.121, 100.200.130.122, and 100.200.130.123. I have three different machines that are behind a firewall, but I want to use SSH to port forward one machine to each IP address. For example: machine-one should listen for SSH on port 22 on 100.200.130.121, while machine-two should do the same on 100.200.130.122, and so on for different services on ports that may be the same across all of the machines.

The SSH man page has `-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport` listed I have gateway ports enabled, but when using `-R` with a specific IP address, server still listens on the port across all interfaces:

#### machine-one:

```
# ssh -NR 100.200.130.121:22:localhost:22 root@hub-server.tld
```

#### hub-server.tld (Listens for SSH on port 2222):

```
# netstat -tan | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 100.200.130.121:2222        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN
```

Is there a way to make SSH forward only connections on a specific IP address to machine-one so I can listen to port 22 on the other IP addresses at the same time, or will I have to do something with iptables? Here are all the lines in my ssh config that are not comments / defaults:

```
Port 2222
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 1000000
UseDNS no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From `sshd_config(5)`:

> GatewayPorts
>
> ```
>   Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to ports forwarded 
>   for the client.  By default, sshd(8) binds remote port forwardings to the
>   loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to 
>   forwarded ports.  GatewayPorts can be used to specify that sshd should 
>   allow remote port forwardings to bind to non-loopback addresses, thus 
>   allowing other hosts to connect.  The argument may be “no” to force remote 
>   port forwardings to be available to the local host only, “yes” to force 
>   remote port forwardings to bind to the wildcard address, or 
>   “clientspecified” to allow the client to select the address to which the 
>   forwarding is bound.  The default is “no”.
> ```

You want to set this to `clientspecified` instead of `yes`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I really wish the man page for ssh(1) stated that `clientspecified` was needed instead of just saying "enabled": "Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5))". From that, I thought it just needed to be set to `yes`.